# How to provide protection to friend function in C++

Tags: c++, friend, friend-function

I have just started learning friend functions in C++.This is the program which I am using for the concept exploration.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class one
{
private:
    int age;
public:
    one()
    {
        age=1;
    }
    void setData(int num)
    {
        age=num;
    }
friend int returnOne(one a);
};
int returnOne(one a)
{
    return a.age;
}


class two
{
private:
    int roll;
public:
    two()
    {
        roll=0;
    }
    void setData(int num)
    {
        roll=num;
    }
friend int returnTwo(two b);
};

int returnTwo(two b)
{
    return b.roll;
}


int main()
{
    one a;
    two b;
    a.setData(10);
    b.setData(12);
    cout<<returnOne(a)<<endl<<returnTwo(b)<<endl;
}
```

Now I am worried that the security of class `one` and `two` has been compromised as now anyone can use those globally defined friend functions to access class `one`'s and class `two`'s private members.
How can I provide protection to these friend functions or restrict their usage?

Comment: You should not think about private/protected/public as security concepts. Making something private or protected does not secure it against malicious users, it's only a design matter to make it easier to write better code.

Answer (score 2):

`friend` ship is mutual. Unless one declares the function as friend in the class definition a function cannot be friended, so it's a choice. If you make it you have to live with it. It makes no sense to make a function friend and then try to prevent it from accessing the class internals because that is exactly the purpose of keyword `friend`.

Do not misuse or misinterpret friendship.
friendship is used to indicate a intentional strong coupling between two entities. If there exists a special relationship between two entities such that one needs access to others private or protected members but You do not want everyone to have access by using the public access specifier then you should use friendship.

Comment: Among those two entities,one entity will be the class whose data members I am accessing usign friend function but the other entity can be anyone as everyone is able to call that function.So how can **You do not want everyone to have access by using the public access specifier then you should use friendship.** be true?

Comment: @InsaneCoder the access is limited to whatever the code of the friend function does, which you decide (although I have seen people do horrible things like declare a friend as a back-door to be implemented by someone else. Don't let anyone tell you it is a good idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a friend function in a class extends the classes `public` interface. You are basically extending the class with more functions (at the cost of tightly coupling those functions).

So you can not stop people using those functions just like you can not stop people using public member methods on your class (they are all part of the public interface).

But you could re-design your friend functions so they do not expose implementation details.
Why not define `operator<<` for your class instead of a functions that access particular members (this is assuming you are providing these functions simply for streaming (if not then the point is mute)).

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s,two const& b)
{
    return s << b.roll;
}
```